# grub: you need to load kernel but cant'find it

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

After making some mistakes on my server the system got stuck in grub rescue. After running the following commands in grub rescue grub2 prompts up.

```
set root=(hd0,1)
set prefix=(hd0,1)/usr/lib/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

In grub2 I run `ls (hd0,1)/`.

results: `vmlinuz var/ usr/ tmp/ sys/ and/ so/ on/`

Then I run `linux /vmlinuz` or `linux (hd0,1)/vmlinuz` but both result in "file not found".

I'm getting a little bit desperate now because of losing all files from this server.

Comment: Is there a `/boot` directory? You don't mention it, and if it's not there the `vmlinuz` file will not be found. `/vmlinuz` is merely a symbolic link to `/boot/vmlinuz-kernel-version-generic`.

Comment: And what mistake was that?

Comment: There is no /boot folder

Comment: I ran rm -R /* in my command line

Comment: You probably have `/boot` on its own partition. Probably best to 1) boot from a Live USB drive 2) backup all your files 3) reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, how did you solve it? I just restarted my laptop and got this error. I am not sure what mistake I made.